# Preparing large fixtures for Django ORM in the case of forward relationship

Tags: pytest-django

I am creating a to-do app where I have a model Project, and this project can have different boards (like Todo, doing, done). The model is like this:

class Project(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(...)

class ProjectBoard(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(...)

So I want to create fixtures for different projects like this:

@pytest.fixture
def project_a():
project = Project.objects.create(name='A')
board_todo = ProjectBoard.objects.create(name='To do', project=project)
board_doing = ProjectBoard.objects.create(name='Doing', project=project)
return project

The question here, is this considered an anti-pattern to create related objects in fixtures ? The described example contains only two models, but what if the number of related models is larger? Pytest recommends that the fixtures should be granulated and small, but I feel like I would like to have different preset projects (like project_a, project_b, project_c, etc...), and not to build it every time for every test.